# How to initialise type, slice of strings, from a list of strings in Go

Tags: go, types

Let's say I have the following:

- a structure

```
type MyStructure struct {
    Field1     int
    CityNames   []string
}
```

-a type, that I used as a response. I created this type just to make the response more suggestive when reading than a slice of strings

```
type CityNamesReponse []string
```

then I have a function where I want to get from my structure just the Names and put it in the response

```
func GetCities() *CityNamesReponse{
   dbResult := MyStructure{
       Field1:   1,
       CityNames: []string{"Amsterdam", "Barcelona"},
   }
   return &CityNameResponse{ dbResult.CityNames}
}
```

I do not want to loop over the data, just want to do it in one go. Tried also:

```
return &CityNameResponse{ ...dbResult.CityNames}
```

Could do it like this, but I am new in Go and a bit confused and would like to do it the right way. This doesn't feel good :

```
    // This works
    c := dbResults.CityNames
    response := make(CityNameResponse, 0)
    response = c
    return &response
```

Thanks

Comment: Won't mere `CityNameResponse(dbResult.CityNames)` work for you?

Comment: Yes, it did. I knew it was something simple but I could not find the syntax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use a pointer to a slice. The pointer probably hurts performance and it complicates the code.

Do use a [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) from `[]string` to `CityNamesReponse`.

```
func GetCities() CityNamesReponse{
   dbResult := MyStructure{
       Field1:   1,
       CityNames: []string{"Amsterdam", "Barcelona"},
   }
   return CityNameResponse(dbResult.CityNames)
}
```

If you feel that you must use a pointer to a slice, then use a [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) from `*[]string` to `*CityNameReponse`.

```
func GetCities() *CityNamesReponse{
   dbResult := MyStructure{
       Field1:   1,
       CityNames: []string{"Amsterdam", "Barcelona"},
   }
   return (*CityNameResponse)(&dbResult.CityNames)
}
```

Comment: thanks. Very helpful was searching for something for this but did not find the syntactics.